# looping through a .txt file in an array JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, text-files

```
public class ThreeSum {

public static int count(int[] a) {
    int n = a.length;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
            for (int k = j+1; k < n; k++) {
                if (a[i] + a[j] + a[k] == 0) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
} 


public static void main(String[] args)  { 

    In input = new In("input.txt");
    int [] a = input.readInts(args[0]);
    StdOut.println(count(a));
} }
```

This is my code. I am trying to read that text file which contains random numbers but every time i run it, i get says to create class In and class StdOut. is there an easier way to run through this file?

Comment: In, StdOut are not Java built-in classes, they don't exists that's why, all the number are on one line ? or one per line ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
```

to get the input. Java's console is not called StdOut, therefore the compiler tells you to create that class. To print to the Java console, you can use

```
System.out.println(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're following Princeton's programming course. If that's the case, you need to read the instructions carefully.

On this page https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/ you can find the description:

> *Classpath.* Put `stdlib.jar` in the same directory as the program you are writing (but do not unjar it). Then, compile and execute as
>   follows:
>
> ### OS X / Linux
>
> ```
> % javac -cp .:stdlib.jar MyProgram.java
> % java  -cp .:stdlib.jar MyProgram
> ```
>
> ### Windows
>
> ```
> % javac -cp .;stdlib.jar MyProgram.java
> % java  -cp .;stdlib.jar MyProgram
> ```

stdlib.jar contains the .java and .class files for the classes `In` and `StdOut` among others.

Answer (score 0):

this is going to read you file line by line

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path p = Paths.get("/Users/ay/Desktop/tx1.txt");
    try(Stream<String> lins = Files.lines(p)) {
        lins.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```